# How to convert a pygame application with multiple modules to .exe

Tags: python, pygame, exe

I have a pygame application which I would like to convert to .exe format.
Pygame2exe (https://pygame.org/wiki/Pygame2exe) works nicely EXCEPT I am unable to figure out how to do this conversion with a project that has more than one custom module.

For example:

```
python_project/
    main.py
    other.py
```

I need to compile both modules, and merging them is not an option.
I have been working at this problem for a few weeks, and have not found any solutions.

I know it is possible, because I had it working, and then formatted the only hard drive that had a copy of the code without realizing I had not made a backup.

EDIT

Thank you Michael.
I just had to make a small change to the setup.py file you provided to make it font compatible. Here is the full setup.py file

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
import os

origIsSystemDLL = py2exe.build_exe.isSystemDLL
def isSystemDLL(pathname):
       if os.path.basename(pathname).lower() in ["sdl_ttf.dll"]:
               return 0
       return origIsSystemDLL(pathname)
py2exe.build_exe.isSystemDLL = isSystemDLL
setup(windows=['main.py'])
```

(taken from [Pygame font not working after py2exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21800218/pygame-font-not-working-after-py2exe))

Thanks again.

Comment: Have you tried py2exe? http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial

Comment: In my experience with py2exe, you can not convert pygame applications to executable files, you need pygame2exe. thanks though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are using python 3.3 or 3.4, you can use py2exe.
install through pip, `pip install py2exe` in cmd
note: if `'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command`, navigate to the directory in which python is installed,/scripts probably: `C:\python34\scripts`

make a setup script called setup.py, 
with just the three lines of code

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe
setup(windows=['filename.pyw']          #probably pyw in windows, will be name of main file
```

then open command prompt in the directory where the main file and setup.py are located, and type  `setup.py py2exe`
DO NOT USE  or filename.pyw in the setup script, use the name of the main module.

this will make a folder called dist, (you can safely get rid of '__pycache_') containing all the files your exe needs to run! 
you will probably want to make an installer, I would recommend Inno Setup (http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php)

Comment: if you have any issues, just comment

Comment: by the way, @CPSuperstore, are you using python3.4 or 3.3 ? because i just tried py2exe with a pygame program and it worked perfectly